# How to play an avi stream in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, avi

I try to play an avi stream in Android. I tried Exoplayer, but it does not seem to work. Is there a player for android capable of playing avi, or can Exoplayer be made to play avi? Does anyone have experience with that?

P.S. I tried the latest Exoplayer (2.10.4).

Answer (score 2):

Exoplayer does not support avi format yet. Check this:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2092

In the meanwhile what you can do is to check if the device that run your app has MXPlayer or VLC and delegate to them this operation. For the most popular video stream format you can continue using Exoplayer library.